# MPMoviePlayer streaming video buffer size

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, buffer, mpmovieplayer

Is there a way to detect how much data has been buffered while streaming video in `MPMoviePlayerController`?

I've already checked `loadState` but that does not give me enough info about buffering.

Youtube's app has exactly what I want...

Comment: you should refere similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346327/mpmovieplayercontroller-when-will-i-know-that-the-downloading-of-the-file-reach

Answer (score 7):

You can try to get movie access log during playing video.

```
- (void)calculateBufferSize
{
    NSArray *events = self.moviePlayerController.accessLog.events;
    int count = events.count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        MPMovieAccessLogEvent *currentEvent = [events objectAtIndex:i];
        int64_t byte = currentEvent.numberOfBytesTransferred;
        int64_t bytes = currentEvent.numberOfBytesTransferred >> 10;

        NSLog(@"byte = %f M bytes = %lld", (float)byte / (1024 * 1024), bytes);
    }
}
```

Then you can call the above by such as,

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(calculateBufferSize) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

after

```
[self.moviePlayerController play];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMovieAccessLog_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010561

Comment: Thanks but I've already get proper nicer solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346327/mpmovieplayercontroller-when-will-i-know-that-the-downloading-of-the-file-reach